# nl2br and str_replace won't work in my CodeIgniter view

Tags: php, codeigniter

Ok so i'm having a bit of an issue with nl2br() and str_replace.

I have a field in my database which is being echoed out. It is added into the database by the user with a textarea in a form.

When it echos out (if the user has added a line) I get \r\n echoing out too.

I tried using nl2b and str_replace, but it still doesnt work. I used str_replace for other items within the same echo, which works fine, but it refuses to work specifically for the \r\n

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
echo str_replace("\r\n", "", $message->message);
```

and

```
echo nl2br($message->message);
```

Neither work. I can't figure it out!

Comment: I'm not using both the above echos together, they are individual. That's just to show what I have tried

Comment: does `$message->message` return the expected value?

Comment: @RikeshShah they are not depending on each other ;)

Comment: @sys.stderr - Yes, it's the correct value.

Comment: Are you saying you get a literal string `\r\n` echoed out in the data? Or that you get an actual CRLF sequence?

Comment: Try `echo str_replace("\r\n", "&nbsp;", $message->message);`

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, never heard that str_replace or nl2br do not work as documented. So the error is likely on your side.

Comment: @DaveRandom - The \r\n are actually in the string even in the database, they are part of the data in the field. The textarea puts the \r\n into the DB when it inserts the user's input. I don't know what CRLF sequence is?

Comment: @Rikesh Sha - That doesn't work.

Comment: @NoahGoodrich CRLF stands for "Carriage Return, Line Feed" - it is the form of line break used on Windows systems. What I meant was, can you see the string `\r\n` in the echoed data, or can you see a line break - and I guess you're saying that you can see the literal string. In this case, all you need to do is change the double quotes `"` to single quotes `'` in your code, and the `str_replace()` will work. Although what you may want to actually do is `echo nl2br(str_replace('\r\n','<br>',$message->message));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks as CI escaped \r\n too. so if you want your regular linebreaks back try it like this

```
$a = " hello \\r\\n world";
echo $a;
// hello \r\n world
```

Now the replace

```
$b = preg_replace('~\\\r\\\n~',"<br>", $a);
echo $b;
// hello <br> world
```

Or

```
$c = preg_replace('~\\\r\\\n~',"\n", $a);
echo $c;
/*
 hello 
 world
*/
```